# Why won't firewalld install?

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I am trying to get firewalld running on a centos 7 machine. I know the service is installed from yum:

```
yum install firewalld
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.linuxfix.com
 * epel: mirrors.develooper.com
 * extras: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * remi: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * remi-php56: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
Package firewalld-0.4.4.4-14.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But when I try to start it I get

```
Failed to start firewalld.service: Unit is masked.
```

Which usually means it is not installed. So I run this command:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

And it is not listed (it should be right after fail2ban)

```
avahi-daemon.service                                            loaded active running Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
chronyd.service                                                 loaded active running NTP client/server
crond.service                                                   loaded active running Command Scheduler
dbus.service                                                    loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
fail2ban.service                                                loaded active running Fail2Ban Service
getty@tty1.service                                              loaded active running Getty on tty1
httpd.service                                                   loaded active running The Apache HTTP Server
iptables.service                                                loaded active exited  IPv4 firewall with iptables
irqbalance.service                                              loaded active running irqbalance daemon
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed several times, rebooted and same result. What could possibly be causing firewalld to not be recognized? I am running 13 VMs and this is the only one with this problem. I also turned of selinux but that didn't help. Any diagnostic suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/710420/why-are-some-systemd-services-in-the-masked-state

Comment: https://stopdisablingselinux.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to `systemctl unmask firewalld`? That's the first step to getting a masked service going.

If you still have trouble, check for the existence of an empty override directory `/etc/systemd/system/firewalld.service.d`. If an override directory exists but has no override files in it, the service cannot start. Delete the directory in this case.

Comment: Yes, I tried unmask. I forgot to mention that. I'll check the directory.

Comment: That was it! It was set to /dev/null. I deleted the symlink, did an unmask and it started right up. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I create the dir /etc/systemd/system/firewalld.service.d, later unmask and mask and ready :)